# Personal Identity Verification

Tags: security, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to implement two-factor authentication (a token you hold, a password you know).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token lists many expensive solutions. I need:

- Strong encryption.
- The ability to **programmatically** reset the private key on the token (multiple times, if the token is expensive) and read the new private key.
- The ability to encrypt a short string (20 characters or less). I believe this means computational power can be very low.
- Something cheap. I'd like to ship these tokens to average consumers (think VISA), if possible.

I don't need:

- To protect against physical attacks on the token (I assume this is beyond the skill of the average attacker).
- To kill the token remotely.
- To store any data on the token aside from the private key.
- Time-dependent tokens (for fear they will fall out of sync).

I plan on doing the following:

- User inserts the token into a PC.
- User enters their password on the keyboard.
- The token encrypts the password using the private key.
- The application sends the result over the network.
- The server decrypts the password using the token's public key. If the password matches I let the user in.

I need to make it reasonably difficult for an average programmer/hacker to read the private key off the token. What are my options? If you believe I am setting the bar too low, what do you suggest?

Comment: I am really not sure what you are asking exactly... it seems you don't give enough information... for example: if this is about security then using the PC keyboard opens up several security problems like being vulnerable to a keyboard logger... also the resetting of private key can be a problem depending on how it is implemented... so: what exactly is the question ?

Comment: @Yahia, I assume that we can't block attackers with physical access to the PC so I'm not even trying. I'm designing a consumer-facing product (think VISA cards) where the price of fraud is limited to exposing <100 personal records. In that sense, I believe the cost is low.

Comment: We might be able to provide more accurate feedback if you can give us an idea of the application this is for. Is the login for a financial application, or something else?

Comment: I understand that but I am NOT talking about physical access to PC but for example an infection with a keyboard logger (malicious software) esp. consumers are more vulnerable to such things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the audience is consumers then it is quite possible that the computer they use is infected somehow - virus/keyboard logger...

IF that is a possibility then the whole scheme becomes risky because of using the PC keyboard...

Putting aside those concerns:
you could run your own "CA" and generate client certificates - these can be put anywhere (USB stick...) and the application could work with them for verifying the user - by just using the passphrase as password etc. - the beauty of this is: you get for example the ability to revoke certificates etc.

another point:
Depending on how your application communicates with the server you could use this scheme to have SSL connections... SSL standard contains the option not only of authenticating the server but also the client by means of a client certificate...

**EDIT**:

anything cheap could be read - smartcards would be better but they are not really cheap and the PC needs additional HW to handle them...

Secure but NOT cheap option:
if you want something secure then you need an external smartcard reader with a keyboard, so that nothing sensitive it entered via PC keyboard - but that is not cheap...

another option (cheaper but still secure):
use the mobile as second channel, they login to your app - the app contacts the server, the server generates some unique and time-limited code and sends it via SMS to their mobile and they need to enter that code to complete login process...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying I should prompt the user for a password, generate a public key protected by that password, send it to them to store on a normal USB stick. Then every time they want to log in, they type in their password, I use that to decrypt the public key and verify if it worked. Sounds good except for the fact that anyone could read the public key off their USB stick. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: please see my edits - added two option (one not so cheap, another one rather cheap+secure)

Comment: I like the SMS approach but the latency is too high. The user needs to get a code within 2-3 seconds of inserting the card. In my experience SMS can take up to 30 minutes depending on your provider and time of day. The smartcard reader + keyboard sounds too expensive as well (> $100 per reader). I'd love to find a secure USB-based solution or a way of predicting when the user will need an SMS a few minutes in advance. Sending SMSs on a regular basis (even once a day) sounds very annoying for the end-user.

Comment: with the SMS approach there is no need for a card... although if your latency is about 30 minutes then that's definitely too high... also you could make the code valid for let's an hour or 8 hours or whatever you like... so the need for codes can be reduced

Comment: Even if I make the codes valid for 24 hours, I think users would find it annoying to get one SMS per day from a service they might only use once a month. Secondly, I am afraid I can't assume that 100% of customers will have cell-phones. Consider the fact that I'm giving out something equivalent to a medicare card.

Answer (score 0):

"The server decrypts the password using the token's public key"

That doesn't make sense. The point of a public key is that can be public without compromising the security of the system. Perhaps what you meant is that the token contains a public key, and the server stores the private key corresponding to that token?

Security tokens are typically not used in the manner you describe. They are quite commonly used as single sign on (SSO) devices. The token generates a pseudo-random number that is time-dependent. In most cases, the number generated changes every 30 or so seconds. The server is configured with the random seed of the token, so it can generate the same number to verify.

Edit: As per your comment, here's my new suggestion:

- Public key on token or client application
- Corresponding private key on server
- It doesn't matter if the public key is read since knowledge of the public key does not help in guessing the private key
- If necessary, change keys at scheduled intervals

Comment: In my case, the public keys aren't really public so they're really interchangeable. Anyway I've updated the question (storing the private key on the server, and public key on the token) as you suggested. Also, I've added more information about my target audience. I think time-based tokens might be too expensive/bulky for them.

Comment: In that case, it doesn't matter if the attacker reads the public key on the token. The beauty of public-key encryption is that anyone can know the public key, but the message can only be deciphered with the private key. Knowing the public key does not help you to guess the private key. Something you should note, though -- if you're using this system, it may not really be necessary to use a physical token at all.

Comment: if the public key is easy to read then I agree there is no point in the physical token. I want something more than just a password. I want the token to deter fraud by increasing the difficulty level. Imagine if VISA didn't give out a physical card and anyone who knew your PIN could withdraw money.

Comment: If that's the case, then the single sign on system works quite well. Is there a specific reason why you can't go with that? Public key encryption isn't going to help you if you want to prevent access from someone who knows the password.

Comment: I just read about SSO systems. That's essentially what I plan on doing. You log in once, and so long as the token is in the drive you don't have to re-enter the password. You log out by pulling out the token.

Comment: Indeed, I figured SSO is what you wanted from the start. After all, it's a security scheme often implemented by financial institutions -- if it's secure enough for them, it's probably secure enough for your purposes.

Comment: What does using SSO really change? Don't I still need a token with public key encryption?

Comment: A token system may use public key encryption, but that's a separate concept from SSO. SSO prevents someone who knows the password from logging in without having the physical token (or a way to guess the next SSO key). Public key encryption can be used to encrypt the password to prevent someone from discovering the password in the first place. Public key encryption does not protect against things like a keylogger. SSO does. Conversely, SSO alone does not protect the password from being intercepted.

Comment: You may be interested in this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password

Comment: One-time passwords sound nice but I don't see a cheap way of implementing them. Remember I am building the equivalent of a medicare card. It has to be under $20 and I can't assume everyone will have a cell-phone (which costs over $20 a month, not per lifetime).

Comment: Well, as a benchmark, I believe hardware SSO tokens cost in the ballpark of $10-15/year per user including licensing costs. See http://www.entrust.com/strong-authentication/identityguard/calculator.cfm for an example.